# Subversion how to branch from one repository to another repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I am new to subversion and tortoisesvn.

I want to take a branch of a code which is in repo whose path is say for example:

http://test.local/svn/test/proj1

to another location say for example:

http://test.local/svn/newlocation/proj1

Can anyone help how to do this? At the moment when I go "TortoiseSVN->Right Click->Copy to" and enter new location I am getting the following error:

> Source and Destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is not distributed . That means you can't take a branch and move to another site that easily.

You can relocate the entire svn instance if all you did was moving the server.

Or you can copy the entire svn database and then remove all code except the branch you need, but that won't actually remove the old checkins so it will still be big.

Or you can export a branch to get it out of svn, and then add it to another svn, but then you loose all history.

Or you can do the very advanced thing of dumping all svn checkins to a text file, edit it to only keep the commits you need and then restore the dump to a new svn database.

Or you can export it to git with gits git-svn function, and after that clean it up and do whatever you want.

Id go with the latter choice!